# I can't put a border to my ul

Tags: css, alignment

I have a list that I want to add a border to it. but when I do this :

```
<ul style="list-style-type: none;padding:3px;margin:3px; ">
    <li style="border:1px dashed; width: 60px; float:left; height: 70px; margin:6px;"></li>
    <li style="border:1px dashed; width: 60px; float:left; height: 70px; margin:6px;"></li>
    <li style="border:1px dashed; width: 60px; float:left; height: 70px; margin:6px;"></li>
 </ul>
```

The li elements look outside of the borders of the ul.
Is there any problem with this code or I'm just using a wrong technique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `overflow:auto;` to your list's CSS:

```
<ul style="list-style-type: none;padding:3px;margin:3px; overflow:auto; ">
```

Comment: Done, sorry i'm a noob on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the li's appear outside the border is because they are set to float:left; and float takes elements outside of the normal flow of their containing elements.  Another solution would be to remove the float:left CSS from each li, and style it a different way (not sure how the rest of your page is set up).